# JSON Object Property not returnable - "Cannot Read Property of Undefined"

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, parsing

Ok, so I'm building out a custom API in React.  When I make the calls, I'm getting JSON data back and store that into local storage with JSON.Stringify:

```
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data))
```

Later, I call this item onto the Homepage to return some of that data once the user is logged in using:

```
var user = JSON.parse([localStorage.getItem('user')])
```

This returns the object:

```
{
"OrderId":0,
"IsLoggedIn":true,
"ModeOfSaleId":64,
"OriginalModeOfSaleId":64,
"SourceId":8580,
"LoginInfo":{"ConstituentId":190554,"OriginalConstituentId":190554,"UserId":"test@email.org","Status":"P","FailedAttempts":0,"LockedDate":null,"ElectronicAddress":"test@email.org"},
"CartInfo":{"PerformanceCount":0,"PackageCount":0,"ContributionCount":0,"MembershipCount":0,"UserDefinedFeeCount":0,"GiftCertificateCount":0,"PaymentCount":0,"FirstSeatAddedDateTime":null},
"BusinessFacing":false,
"IsGuest":false,
"CheckoutStatus":{"Status":"No Checkout","Date":null},
"HasLockedSeats":false,
"SeatsExpired":false
}
```

**The Issue:**

Un-nested properties return normally `{user.OrderId}` or `{user.ModeOfSaleId}` However, trying to return the nested values like `{user.LoginInfo.ConstituentID}` result in the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ConstituentId' of undefined
```

Returning `{user.LoginInfo}` actually returns an object, but obviously, can't print that to a string. Returning `{user.LoginInfo["ConstituentId"]}` results in the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ConstituentId' of undefined
```

So yeah, I'm stumped, I don't know how I'm returning this incorrectly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify({
   "OrderId":0,
   "IsLoggedIn":true,
   "ModeOfSaleId":64,
   "OriginalModeOfSaleId":64,
   "SourceId":8580,
   "LoginInfo":{"ConstituentId":190554,"OriginalConstituentId":190554,"UserId":"test@email.org","Status":"P","FailedAttempts":0,"LockedDate":null,"ElectronicAddress":"test@email.org"},
   "CartInfo":{"PerformanceCount":0,"PackageCount":0,"ContributionCount":0,"MembershipCount":0,"UserDefinedFeeCount":0,"GiftCertificateCount":0,"PaymentCount":0,"FirstSeatAddedDateTime":null},
   "BusinessFacing":false,
   "IsGuest":false,
   "CheckoutStatus":{"Status":"No Checkout","Date":null},
   "HasLockedSeats":false,
   "SeatsExpired":false
}));

const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

console.log(user.LoginInfo.OriginalConstituentId);
```

Comment: Still getting a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'OriginalConstituentId' of undefined` could it be something with React?

Comment: Where in the react lifecycle are you setting / getting the data? One thing that is coming to mind is the way that react handles rendering, the component will render once before fetching your data, so it's possible that the entire sub object you're trying to access doesn't exist yet. ```Cannot read property 'OriginalConstituentId' of undefined``` means that LoginInfo isn't defined either, so the user object could just be an empty object. Try adding an if statement before, like:
```if (user.LoginInfo) <do something with user.LoginInfo.OriginalConstituentId>```

Comment: You are partially correct. This was happening because of the way React's `render()` function fires before `componentDidMount()`. See my answer for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What about using spread operator to get what you want?

```
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
const { ConstituentId, UserId } = user.LoginInfo

console.log(ConstituentId) // 190554
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ConstituentId' of undefined` error. Which is weird, because I found out I can `console.log(user.LoginIfo)` with no problem and even wrap a nested element in an array: `const { ConstituentId, UserId } = [user.LoginInfo]` and console log it with the `0` item as the nested object. However, I still can't access anything inside!

Comment: Any attempt to access a property inside results in it being delcared as undefined, for example: `const login = user.LoginInfo console.log(login)`  returns an obj normally. `console.log(login.ConstituentId)` does not. I even tried `const login = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user.LoginIfo))` but that returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` Ugh! Could this be something inherent in React? Specific way to call a nested obj correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the way I'm returning these values seems to be an "issue" because of the way React handles it's Render event. When I'm pulling in the data on the `componentDidMount()` event, a Render event still fires just before this.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ 
    user: JSON.parse([localStorage.getItem('user')]),
    users: { loading: true }
  });
}
```

So in the Render event:

```
render() {
    const { user, users, loading } = this.state;
    var { ConstituentId, UserId } = user.LoginInfo


    return (
        <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h1>Hi!</h1>
            <p>{UserId}</p>
            <p>You're logged in with React & Basic HTTP Authentication!!</p>
            <h3>Users from secure api end point:</h3>
            <p>
                <Link to="/login">Logout</Link>
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

It fires TWICE, once BEFORE the `state.user` is set by `componentDidMount()` and once again after. So, my code was erroring out because of the first firing of Render, when nothing was set, hence the `undefined` message. I figured out how to bypass this with checking the login info object is returning as `typeof object`. This is in my render event:

```
var result = (typeof user.loginInfo === 'object');

if (result && loading) {
    console.log(result)
    console.log(user.LoginInfo.ConstituentId)
    var { ConstituentId, UserId } = user.LoginInfo
}
```

But that's not very elegant. So, ultimately I re-wrote how I was handling unloaded information in `componentDidMount()` by creating a state prop called 'loading':

```
this.state = {
  loading: true,
  user: {}
};
```

In `componentDidMount()` I'm doing this:

```
this.setState({ 
  user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')),
  loading: false
});
```

And in `render()`:

```
const { loading, user } = this.state;
if (!loading) {
  var { ConstituentId, UserId } = user.LoginInfo
}
console.log(ConstituentId)
```

It works great!

Basically, I'm just waiting for `componentDidMount()` to fire using the `loading` state by setting it to `false` in the function. Then we know it's loaded and can successfully render the data.